# When try to fetch data from firebase - null check operator used on a null value - Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to fetch data from firestore and display them.

When I call `VendorModel vendor = VendorModel.fromJson(snapshot.data!() as Map<String, dynamic>);`
it throws me an exception saying...
**null check operator used on a null value**

Here are my files

**vander_home.dart**

```
class VendorHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const VendorHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final FirebaseService _service = FirebaseService();

    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: _service.vendor.doc(_service.user!.uid).snapshots(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: Colors.red,
          );
        }

        VendorModel vendor =
            VendorModel.fromJson(snapshot.data!() as Map<String, dynamic>);

        return Text(
          vendor.businessName!,              
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**vander_model.dart**

```
class VendorModel {
  VendorModel({
    this.businessName,
  });

  VendorModel.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
      : this(
          businessName: json['businessName']! as String,
        );

  final String? businessName;

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() {
    return {
      'businessName': businessName,
    };
  }
}
```

**firebase_service.dart**

import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;

```
class FirebaseService {
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  final CollectionReference vendor =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('vendor');

  firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage storage =
      firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance;

  Future<void> addVendor({Map<String, dynamic>? data}) {
    return vendor.doc(user!.uid).set(data);
  }
}
```

How to solve this?

---

---

---

I found a way to do this.

But anyone can help me to how go through my above problem please help me.

```
class VendorHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const VendorHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final FirebaseService _service = FirebaseService();

    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: _service.vendor.doc(_service.user!.uid).snapshots(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: Colors.red,
          );
        }

        if (!snapshot.data!.exists) {
          return const BusinessRegisterScreen();
        }

        var docc = snapshot.data;

        return Text(
          docc!['businessName'],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Without using **VendorModel**...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `!` on null value, so change this :

```
VendorModel vendor = VendorModel.fromJson(snapshot.data!() as Map<String, dynamic>);
```

to this:

```
VendorModel vendor = VendorModel.fromJson( snapshot.data == null ? {}: snapshot.data as Map<String, dynamic>);
```

also in your `VendorModel` model class change this:

```
VendorModel.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
      : this(
          businessName: json['businessName']! as String,
        );
```

to

```
VendorModel.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
      : this(
          businessName: json['businessName'] != null ? json['businessName'] as String : "",
        );
```

Comment: It's not working. When I trying to change `VendorModel vendor = VendorModel.fromJson(snapshot.data!() as Map<String, dynamic>);` it says **The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.** and **The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be 'null'. Try adding a null check ('!').**. When I did both **The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true. Remove the condition.** it telling me this.

Comment: No something else. What is the cause to this error? Everything works properly until calling to VendorModel

Comment: why are you calling snapshot.data() instead of snapshot.data?

Comment: Sorry that line should be corrected as `VendorModel vendor =VendorModel.fromJson(snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);`. I missed some sorry

Comment: I updated my answer right now, check it out

Comment: Still throwing **null check operator used on a null value** exception

Comment: I updated my answer again, check it out.

Comment: Still the same bro. I found another way and it is working fine but I can't understand what is wrong with this code. I put my answer below.

Comment: I asked you that first, if you want to get snapshot's data you just needed to call snapshot.data.